# LWJGL Applet Loader

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl

I'm new to working with Java, and I want to upload a basic LWJGL applet to my website and play it in the browser.  I have no idea how to do it, and I want to make sure I know how to get it working before I keep working on my game.   Please help me because I have no idea how to embed a JWJGL applet, or any other kind of applet, to a site and run it from a browser.  I am using Eclipse.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on the lwjgl wiki, have you seen it?

[Basic Applet](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Basic_LWJGL_Applet)

[Applet Loader Introduction](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Deploying_with_the_LWJGL_Applet_Loader_-_Introduction)